# Angular 1.5 component check '& binding' is null

Tags: angularjs, angular-components

Please, help me on this point.

I have an angular 1.5 component using '& binding':

```
app.component('foo', {
    bindings: {
       message: '<'
       onSomething: '&'
    },
    template:'<div>blah blah</div>',
    controller: function () {
       var ctrl = this;
       ctrl.myOperation = function () {
           ctrl.onSomething();   // <= look this!
       }
    }
});
```

And I'd like to test if 'onSomething' is defined.

In fact, if I use it in this way:

```
<foo message='my message' on-something='doSomething()'></foo>
```

all is ok.

But if I use it in this way:

```
<foo message='my message'></foo>
```

'onSomething' should not be defined, **but I am not able to check it!**

I tried:

```
if (ctrl.onSomething) ...
if (ctrl.onSomething == undefined) ...
if (ctrl.onSomething == null) ...
if (angular.isDefined(ctrl.onSomething)
```

all these tests always return 'true', even when the callback has not been passed.

Comment: Pretty sure you could change `'&'` to `'&?'` and then you'll see `ctrl.onSomething === null`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They return `true` because `ctrl.onSomething` is a hook function for initiating the callback declared in the instance of the component.  It will always be *truthy*.  Instead, try injecting `$attrs` into your controller and null-check it.

```
function( $attrs ){
    var ctrl = this;
    ctrl.myOperation = function(){
        if( $attrs.onSomething ){ .... }
    }
}
```

Comment: This happen when someone studies a technology too fast: I didn't know $attr. Thank you!

Comment: There are subtle differences betw. a directive and component, mostly in how the controller is added and when.  Because you don't get a linking function in a component, they've added the $element and $attrs services for the component to be injected to achieve the same functionality as in a directive's link function.